# Injecting a service in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm sort of refactoring some legacy code and I've written a service that I would like to be injected into a constructor of a class. There're two important things to note about this class.
The first thing is that it's instantiated by a factory and the second thing is that it's a parent for another class.

```
class A extends AParent implements IA {
    constructor(
        protected someService: SomeService,
    )
}


class B extends A {
    constructor(
        protected someService: SomeService,
    )
    super(someService);
}
```

Now the factory says that it can't instantiate the A class because its constructor requires an argument which is the service.

What is the right way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno, could it be an answer, but anyway.

```
class A extends AParent implements IA {
  constructor(protected someService: SomeService) // Removing `,` after service argument
  {
    // Forgotten `{}` brackets.
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor()
  {
    // Since you already have an instance of `SomeService` in parent class
    // I think you don't need to pass it to constructor of class B.
  }
}
```